# OneNote Interop PrintOut

Tags: c#, office-interop, onenote

Is there a way to insert a file as a print out to OneNote using C#? I have been able to insert files and image as attachment / Inserted files but I can't seem to find a way to access the Print Out functionality.

Comment: Are you using COM APIs to talk to the OneNote 2013 Win32 app, or REST API to talk to the OneNote service?

Answer (score 0):

You can set OneNote as an active printer and print directly there. For example, see [Excel Geeking: Sending A Selection To OneNote With VBA](http://scottlyerly.wordpress.com/2014/03/21/excel-geeking-sending-a-selection-to-onenote-with-vba/) .